# Pandas dataframe execution speed question

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have input pandas dataframe like below. The content in 'index_vec' column is of string type.

[image]

I want to add a set of columns with column names representing the values in the 'index_vec' column, and with values representing the counts of that value in 'index_vec'. An example is like below:

[image]

It shows the 0-th row of the '-1' column is incremented by 1, and the 2nd row of the '-2' column is incremented by 1 as well. Note that there are many columns that are not shown, due to the size of the dataframe. I have the following code and wonder how it can be further improved for execution speed.

```
for i in range (neg_index, pos_index):
  df[str(i)]= 0
  df[str(i)]= df[str(i)].astype(np.int16)

def add_counts(x):
  # take the string rep of the list and make it into an actual python list of strings
  index_vec = [str(x) for x in ast.literal_eval(x['index_vec'])]
  x[set(index_vec)] = x[set(index_vec)] + [index_vec.count(i) for i in set(index_vec)]
  return x

df=df.apply(add_counts, axis = 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can actually be done in a one liner!

With your data frame that looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'index_vec': ["[370, -1, -1]", "[1201, 1201]", "[-2, 676, 676]", "[641, 641]", "[811, 811]"]})

        index_vec
0   [370, -1, -1]
1    [1201, 1201]
2  [-2, 676, 676]
3      [641, 641]
4      [811, 811]
```

We can split the convert the index vector column to a `pd.Series` and apply `value_counts` this will create all the columns you need and their counts per respective row. Then we join that new df to the old one:

```
df.join(df['index_vec'].str.strip("[]").str.split(", ").apply(pd.Series.value_counts).fillna(0).astype(np.int16))
```

output:

```
        index_vec   -1  370  1201  676   -2  641  811
0   [370, -1, -1]  2.0  1.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
1    [1201, 1201]  0.0  0.0   2.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
2  [-2, 676, 676]  0.0  0.0   0.0  2.0  1.0  0.0  0.0
3      [641, 641]  0.0  0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  2.0  0.0
4      [811, 811]  0.0  0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  2.0
```

full code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'index_vec': ["[370, -1, -1]", "[1201, 1201]", "[-2, 676, 676]", "[641, 641]", "[811, 811]"]})

df = df.join(df['index_vec'].str.strip("[]").str.split(", ").apply(pd.Series.value_counts).fillna(0).astype(np.int16))
```

edit:

Just wanting to add, I *presume* this will be faster than your current method because it will only create columns that are present in the `index_vec` list- whereas using the range may create excess columns that may not actually ever appear. Additionally, when you create columns in that loop you are adding one column to the data frame `x` times.. but here you are adding `x` columns to the df 1 time.

However, without the full data to run a timer between the two implementations- I can't really be sure... but hopefully this speeds it up for you.

Edit:
Extra columns are needed:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

neg_index = -100
pos_index = 2000

df = pd.DataFrame({'index_vec': ["[370, -1, -1]", "[1201, 1201]", "[-2, 676, 676]", "[641, 641]", "[811, 811]"]})
df = df.join(df['index_vec'].str.strip("[]").str.split(", ").apply(pd.Series.value_counts).fillna(0).astype(np.int16))

uninitialized = list(set([str(x) for x in range(neg_index, pos_index)]).difference(df.columns.values.tolist()))
df[uninitialized] = pd.DataFrame([[0]*len(uninitialized)], index=df.index)
```

Comment: Thanks again, Anna. Your pandas skills are very impressive. I would need all the columns that may not exist in the current index_vec column though, because new data keep coming in. I want to have a fixed size (column-wise) dataframe to go into the ML model.  The existing code, thanks to your contribution, is already 8X faster than the original iterrows approach!

Comment: no problem! Though, out of curiosity, wouldn't you need to rerun (either code) as the data gets updated? because in that case, this would just produce all columns present in `index_vec`. However, your previous code is creating them all even if they are not there yet... and unless you are creating these in increments then preforming a merge at the end, which having the columns all present in every data frame you are merging would make it faster, I don't see the necessity in doing that per every time you run this code..

Comment: also, I am just assuming how you may be using this code/reading in the data, so I could be totally wrong here

Comment: There are training datasets and there are test datasets from the live data streams. The two needs to have the same columns. So I thought that I just create a dataset that has all possible columns. If you have a better idea, I am all ears. (or all eyes in this case :-)

Comment: I added a little code snippet at the bottom to initialize the columns that are not present in the `index_vect`, but if you'd like I can send you a DM tomorrow to chat about your code because if I knew more about how you are feeding these into to the ML model/reading them in, I could definitely be more help here.. and I can't resist a good code optimization problem. :)

Comment: I appreciate your kind offer, Anna. Sure, please do send me a DM and I'll tell you more about what I am up to. Thanks again.